# Protect directory for public access

Tags: javascript, html, apache

I need to protect all files in a directory called "files".

The directory structure is like this:

- root web-app
-- /js/
-- /img/
-- /files/
-- index.php

The access shall be denied when I try to get
http://root web-app/files/xyz.pdf

On the other hand I need access by javascript like this:

```
var myObject = document.createElement("object");
var myObjectAtt = document.createAttribute("data"); 

myObjectAtt.nodeValue = pdfFileDataObject.file;
myObject.setAttributeNode(myObjectAtt);

var myObjectType = document.createAttribute("type");
myObjectType.nodeValue = "application/pdf";
myObject.setAttributeNode(myObjectType);
myObject.style.width            = "480px";          
myObject.style.height           = "640px";
```

Comment: Either the client can access it or they can't.  If I'm understand right you're saying you don't want to be able to browse to a file, but you want Javascript to be able to access it.  Any method you chose to do that will mean the file is totally accessible.

Comment: Thanks. Will solve it with AJAX (PHP and JavaScript).